# Canny vs Sobel. Why Canny is not able to detect edges?

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator, sobel

I am having a 16 bit image from which I am trying to detect edges. I converted the image to 8 bit and then applied edge detection. I am getting edges using Sobel, however, Canny doesn't detect edges.

Why does this happen ?

The original image is attached here.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY0KI.png)

The code is given below:

```
from skimage import feature
from skimage import filters
#Read image
image = cv2.imread("Path_to_img",0)
edge_sobel = filters.sobel(image)
edges_canny = feature.canny(image, sigma=0)
```

Comment: `sigma=0`, what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the meaning of `sigma=0` is that there is no noise, and every tiny bit of noisy pixels is considered to be an edge. `sigma=0` detects the maximum total edges, so it seems like a good way for testing the case where no edges are detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the Canny edge detector is related to the fact that the original image has a very low "dynamic range".

`image.min()` = `9`
`image.max()` = `15`
The dynamic range is only 15-9 = `6` (up to 7 levels of gray).

The Canny has two optional threshold arguments, described [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/_canny.py):

> `low_threshold` : float, optional
> Lower bound for hysteresis thresholding (linking edges).
> If None, low_threshold is set to 10% of dtype's max.
> `high_threshold` : float, optional
> Upper bound for hysteresis thresholding (linking edges).
> If None, high_threshold is set to 20% of dtype's max.

According to the documentation, defaults for `uint8` type are:
`low_threshold = 255*0.1` = `25.5` and `high_threshold= 255*0.2` = `51`.

Since the pixel levels range of the `image` is only 6 (and not 255), none of the edges passes the threshold, and no edge is detected.

---

We may compute `drange` and set `low_threshold` = `drange*0.1` and `high_threshold` = `drange*0.2`:

```
drange = image.max() - image.min()  # 6
edges_canny = feature.canny(image, sigma=1.5, low_threshold=drange*0.1, high_threshold=drange*0.2)
```

---

An alternative solution is applying `cv2.normalize` before Canny (linear "stretching" the image to range [0, 255]):

```
norm_image = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
edges_canny_norm = feature.canny(norm_image, sigma=1.5)
```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
from skimage import feature
from skimage import filters
#Read image
image = cv2.imread("Path_to_img.png", 0)
edge_sobel = filters.sobel(image)

drange = image.max() - image.min()  # 6 (the image has only 7 levels of grays)
edges_canny = feature.canny(image, sigma=1.5, low_threshold=drange*0.1, high_threshold=drange*0.2)

norm_image = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
#edges_canny_norm = feature.canny(norm_image, sigma=1.5)
cv2.imshow('norm_image', norm_image)
cv2.imshow('edges_canny', edges_canny.astype('uint8')*255)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:

[image]